# new QCustomPlot() C++ -> program exists with exit code 1

Tags: c++, qt, qcustomplot

I am trying to instantiate a new QCustomPlot variable 
QCustomPlot* plot = new QCustomPlot();

Program exits after executing this line. There is no error in compilation or after program exits.

Am I missing something?

What is the solution for this issue?

---

Solution - Rebuilt the library and it worked

Comment: Any output? Did you run it in a debugger?

Comment: Also, can you provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) compliant example?

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld - I was debugging the program in visual studio 2010. Program exits when new memory is being allocated i.e. new QCustomPlot()

Comment: Rebuilding the QCustomPlot library worked